# Automate displaying Attributes column in Windows File Manager

Tags: filesystems, file-properties, virtualfilesystem, desktop.ini

I am trying to automate displaying the Attributes column in Windows File manager in the Details view. This column should be displayed for a specific folder only (not for all folders in the system). As far as I know, this could be made via a desktop.ini file.

I have placed the desktop.ini file in the folder, marked it as a system, hidden, and read-only. I have also tried marking the folder in which my desktop.ini is located as system and read-only.

My desktop.ini partially works, at least I was able to change the folder icon. I guess I describe the Attributes column incorrectly. Here is my desktop.ini file:

```
[{B725F130-47EF-101A-A5F1-02608C9EEBAC}]
Prop4=13,Attributes
```

Here is the Attributes column that I am trying to automate:
[image: How to automate displaying attributes column in Windows File Manager]

Comment: as I know it's impossible. details view shows data depended on file type, not folder settings. you can get more info about `desktop.ini` [here](https://hwiegman.home.xs4all.nl/desktopini.html)

Comment: @DaniilLoban What is ".[{F29F85E0-4FF9-1068-AB91-08002B27B3D9}] Prop2 = 31,Title" in the Desktop.ini documentation? Ist it a description of a column (or description of the column data)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I know it's impossible. details view shows data depended on file type, not folder settings. you can get more [info](https://hwiegman.home.xs4all.nl/desktopini.html) about desktop.ini

**So what can we do using the file desktop.ini?**

Sadly, in Windows, folders are folders while in unix, folders are files so metatags cannot be added to them in Windows....

*The reason `desktop.ini` works is because that file is used to keep a folders layout view and its parameters. Since it is a relation to the folder, you can add anything to it and **it will be information about the folder**.*

For example I created test folder and put in it desktop.ini:

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
IconResource=C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll,15
[ViewState]
Mode=
Vid=
FolderType=Generic
[{F29F85E0-4FF9-1068-AB91-08002B27B3D9}]
    Prop2 = 31,My folder
    Prop3 = 31,secret
    Prop4 = 31,John Doe
    Prop5 = 31,how it works
    Prop6 = 31,this is comment
```

where:

```
Prop2 = 31,Title
Prop3 = 31,Subject
Prop4 = 31,Author
Prop5 = 31,Keywords(Tags)
Prop6 = 31,Comment
```

[more info](https://excelfox.com/forum/showthread.php/2192-All-Extended-Property-Of-Windows-Based-Files)

When i go to a higher level i can see these properties:

[image]

**But some solution exist**

I think this is close to what you want, but not completely because for all folders.

[How to Customize the Details Pane in Windows 10](https://winaero.com/customize-details-pane-windows-10/)

result:

[image]

I think it's impossible to set columns in folder automatically because it does deep in Windows:

The code and settings that remembered individual folder window size and position are gone (along with the ability to set an arbitrary icon order as opposed to sorting on a property). I think this disappeared in the transition from XP to Vista.
However, your view mode (Details, List, Icons, etc.), column choices, and sort order should be remembered for individual folders. If they aren't, it's possible you've reached the limit (5000) for saved views. To check, copy & paste the following command into a PowerShell window:

```
((gp 'HKCU:\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU').NodeSlots).count
```

when you add some setting for the forder this number will increase (i checked it)

This is path in `RegEdit`:

```
HKCU:\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU
and
HKCU:\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags
```

And when I created new folder and add `Attributes` column in it, I saw in `RegEdit` this:

[image]

As you can see, `no paths`, `no names`

**But**

[there is also a software solution](http://%20https://www.shellboost.com/Doc/Developer-s-Guide/Item-properties-folder-columns)

[Explorer column interaction (get/set: which appear, width, ascending/descending order)](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=33129)

**The End**

Comment: Will the "Title", "Authors" and "Subject" columns be displayed automatically on the parent folder when you add desktop.ini or you need to make them visible via the context menu on columns?

Comment: yes you should do it from context menu only for the first time, then the system should store them, probably somehow through a register not through a ini file

Comment: I discovered an interesting feature. I selected columns, then renamed the folder, the columns disappeared, but when I returned the name, the columns returned.

Comment: I need these columns to appear automatically, either via desktop.ini, via the registry, or by any other means. I can not show them manually via the context menu, unfortunately. Columns must appear only in some folders, but not in the other.

Comment: @ITHitWebDAV I updated my answer, It's full now, best regards.